# multilingual website php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multilingual

For the past few days I've been  stuck with creating a PHP-based multilingual website. I've tried a great deal of solutions but had no luck so far.

This is how I would like my URL's to look:
http://www.example.com/en/about
http://www.example.com/cs/o-nas
etc.

I've been using this rewrite rule BEFORE I decided to implement multilingual support and it worked just fine:

```
RewriteBase /kittytea/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?page=$1 [L]
```

My links look like this:

```
<a href="about">
```

Has anyone got an idea how to add the multilingual support? I'm familiar with passing URL parameters using the GET method.

I might add that I'm using a simple PHP SWITCH statement for loading individual website sections.

PS - It's a very small website and I don't need a top notch solution. I just want to make it work :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try including the 2 letter language code as part of the rewrite:

```
RewriteBase /kittytea/

# with language
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]

# original, without language
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?page=$1 [L]
```

Your php script would then need to check for the 2 letter language code in the `lang` parameter and return the appropriate content.

Then you'd need to change your links to:

```
<a href="en/about">
```

Comment: One could even combine them into one rule `RewriteRule ^(([a-z]{2})/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?lang=$2&page=$3 [L]`

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work fine, however, my CSS and images stopped loading. I believe it has something to do with the artificial "/en" directory in the URL. I looked up some solution to this but none of them worked.

Comment: @OndraMatoušek because of the extra path, you need to either use absolute URLs for your css/images/scripts or you can try adding `<base href="/">` in the header of your pages (or whatever the URI base should be).

Comment: Thanks Jon! It works like a clock. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @OndraMatoušek You should check the green checkmark so that your question gets listed as resolved.

Comment: How to do that when using a public folder?